# Linux HD not visible in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I've just received a new laptop and i'm trying to install a linux on it as a primary (and only one) OS. I've already done it hundreds of times in my life so we can assume i'm pretty familiar with the process. However, that's the first time i'm getting such issue and can't find any helpfull topic on the internet.

Here is the thing. I've installed xubuntu 16.04 using bootable USB and everything went fine. After restarting my PC (first restart after installation), i was not able to chose my HD device on GRUB screen. It was basically not there.

When i'm using my bootable USB to run linux on liveCD mode, i can totally see that hard drive, i can see that system is installed there and i can access all the files. Disk is not corrupted and everything is in place. It's just like GRUB don't want to show me that HD for some reason.

**The same applies to ElementaryOS** - i've also tried to install ElementaryOS and the scenario was exactly the same - everything went fine, files were in place but disk was not visible in GRUB.

If you need any more info, i will be more than happy to answer any of your questions.

ps. i'm on Acer Aspire V

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be fixable by [Boot Repair tool](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10871917#post10871917)

But it's still weird i needed to use it on clean installation.